# Show that $\lbrace x_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \rbrace \cup \lbrace x \rbrace$ is a compact subset of $(X,d)$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, and $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a
>   sequence in $X$, with $x_n \rightarrow x \in X$ (w.r.t the usual
>   metric $d$). Show that $\lbrace x_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \rbrace \cup
> \lbrace x \rbrace$ is a compact subset of $(X,d)$

Need step by step proof!

These are my thoughts:
I know to show $(X,d)$ is a compact subspace I have to show that every open cover of $X$ has a finite subcover.

This means I must first show $(X,d)$ is an open cover of *(what?)*
But, isn't the singleton $\lbrace x \rbrace$ closed in $(X,d)$? Also, I suspect this a gross misunderstanding, but if $x_n \rightarrow x \in X$ (w.r.t the usual metric $d$), then is it wrong to interpret the union in question to be:

$\lbrace x \rbrace \cup \lbrace x \rbrace$?

Comment: You do not want to show that $(X,d)$ is compact, but that $A:=\{x_n:n\in \mathbb N\}\cup \{x\}$ is compact.

Comment: The set $\{x_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is not the sequence (which is a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $X$) nor its limit. We are taking the set of the image of the sequence together with the limit. So in general we have an infinite set.

Answer (score 7):

For an open cover of $\{x_n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{x\}$ there is an open set $U$ from the cover with $x\in U$ and because $x_n\to x$ there is a $N\in \mathbb{N}$ with $x_m\in U$ forall $m>N$. So when we chose for every $m\leq N$ an open set $U_m$ from the cover with $x_m\in U_m$  we get a finite subcover by the open sets $U_m, m\leq N$ and $U$ and so $\{x_n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{x\}$ is compact.

Comment: How do we know we can take an open cover of $\lbrace x_n | n \in \mathbb{N} \rbrace \cup \lbrace x \rbrace$?

Comment: We can for every element chose an open neighbourhood, but this is not really relevant. Recall for showing compactness we must show that if we have an open cover we get a finite subcover. Nobody wants to know here how we get the open cover.

Comment: @Jayant.M You don't have to pick an open cover. We start with an *arbitrary* open cover of the set and show it has a finite subcover. This is what compactness means by definition.

Comment: Maybe I should chose a better formulation, what I've tried now.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $S:=\{x_n: n\in \mathbb N\}\cup \{x\}$. Since $(X,d)$ is a metric space, then showing that $S$ is compact is equivalent to showing that $S$ is sequentially compact: that every sequence in $S$ has a convergent subsequence whose limit is in $S$. Now the convergence of $x_n$ to $x$ implies that any subsequence of $x_n$ converges also to $x$.

Comment: +1 Obviously easier as my proof if the characterisation of compactness in metric spaces as sequentially compactness is known.

Comment: @sigmabe Actually, this proof is more complicated when it comes to the details. For example, not every sequence in $S$ is a subsequence of $x_n$. For a complete proof, you need to consider some specific cases (does the sequence contain infinitely many different values etc.).

Comment: Ok, that is one possible position, but I think there are still people thinking this prove is more intuitve, it's always tricky to talk about "easiest proof", https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_twenty-fourth_problem

Answer (score 0):

If $\lim_{n\to \infty}d(x,x_n)=0,$ then, by the def'n of $\lim$, whenever $r>0$, the set $\{n: x_n\not \in B_d(x,r)\}$ is finite (where $B_d(x,r)=\{y: d(x,y)<r\}$).

$U$ is an open subset of $X$ iff for every $y\in U$ there exists $r_y>0$ such that $B_d(y,r_y)\subset U.$

For brevity let $A=\{x\}\cup \{x_n: n\in N\}.$ Let $C$ be an open cover of $A.$ There exists $U_0\in C$ with $x\in U_0,$ and there exists $r_x>0$ such that $B_d(x,r_x)\subset U_0$.

Let $S=\{n:x_n\not \in B_d(x,r_x)\}.$ Then $S$ is finite. For each $n\in S$ there exists $U_n\in C$ such that $x_n\in U_n.$

Then $C^*=\{U_0\}\cup \{U_n:n\in S\}$ is a finite subset of $C.$ And $C^*$ is a cover of $A .$ Because: (i). $x\in U_0.$ (ii) If $n\not\in S$ then $x_n\in B_d(x,r_x)\subset U_0.$ (iii). If $n\in S$ then $x_n\in U_n.$

Remark. It is useful that, in a metric space, a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in N}$ converges to $x$ iff $\{n:x_n\not \in U\}$ is finite for every nbhd $U$ of $x.$

Answer (score 0):

> In a metric space $X$, let $x_n$ be a sequence that converges to the element $a$. Then the set $M=\left\{a, x_1, x_2, \ldots\right\}$ is compact.

**Solution 1.**

We consider that the set $M$ is cover compact (compact). Let $(O_\lambda)_{\lambda \in \lambda}$ be an open covering of $M$, that is, every set $O_\lambda \subseteq X$ is open and, moreover, it holds that
$$
    M \subseteq \bigcup_{\lambda \in \lambda} O_\lambda.
\tag{1}
$$
To prove that $M$ is cover compact, we need to show that $M$ can only be covered by finitely many of the open sets (finite partial cover). First, because of (1), there is an index $\lambda_0 \in \lambda$ with $a \in O_{\lambda_0}$. Thus $a$ is an interior point of the open set $O_{\lambda_0}$, which is why we find a number $\varepsilon>0$ with $B_{\varepsilon}(a) \subseteq O_{\lambda_0}$. As usual, here $B_{\varepsilon}(a)$ denotes the open ball around $a$ with radius $\varepsilon$.

Since the sequence $\left(x_n\right)_n$ converges to $a$ by premise there is by definition a natural number $N \in \mathbb{N}$ which depends on $\varepsilon$, with
$$
d(x_n,a)<\varepsilon \quad \text{ or equivalently } \quad x_n \in B_{\varepsilon}(a) \quad \forall\, n \geq N.
$$
But this means just $x_n \in O_{\lambda_0}$ for all $n \geq N$. Thus, except for finitely many sequence members, all members lie in the open set $O_{\lambda_0}$. Finally, because of (1), for every $j \in\{1, \ldots, N-1\}$ we find an index $\lambda_j \in \Lambda$ and an open set $O_{\lambda_j}$ with $a_j \in O_{\lambda_j}$.
Let us now write
$$
M=\{x_1, \ldots, x_{N-1}\} \cup\{x_n \in X \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \text { with } n \geq N\} \cup\{a\},
$$
so with our considerations it follows as desired
$$
M \subseteq \bigcup_{j=1}^{N-1} O_{\lambda_j} \cup O_{\lambda_0},
$$
that is, we have found a finite partial cover of the set $M$.

Thus, as desired, we have shown that the set $M$ is compact.

---

**Solution 2.**

We will prove that the set $M$ is sequence compact (compact). To do this, we need to show that every sequence from $M$ has a convergent subsequence. To this end, let $(y_n)_n \subseteq M$ be any sequence. We distinguish the following two cases:

**(a)** The sequence takes a value in $M$ any number of times. Thus the sequence $(y_n)_n$ automatically has a constant subsequence which is obviously convergent.

**(b)** The sequence takes any value from $M$ only finitely often. Let us define for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ the set
$$
M_k=\left\{x_j \in X \mid j \in\{1, \ldots, k\}\right\},
$$
then for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists at least one index
$$
N_k \in \mathbb{N}: x_n \notin M_{N_k}\quad \forall\, n \geq N_k.
$$
Now let $\varepsilon>0$ be arbitrary. Since the sequence $ (y_n )_n$ converges to $a$ by precondition,
$$
\exists\, K \in \mathbb{N}: d(y_n-a)<\varepsilon\quad \forall\,n \geq K.
$$
Thus, for $n \geq N_K$ it follows.
$$
d(y_n-a)=d(x_n-a)<\varepsilon,
$$
that is, the subsequence $(y_n)_n$ also converges to $a$.

Thus, as desired, we have shown that the set $M$ is compact.